# Trying to give a room object connecting rooms to the NSEW in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to add rooms to the N,S,E,W of every room I create using this function;

```
typedef struct
{
     object roomObject;
     int status;
     Creature creaturesInRoom[10];
     Room n,s,e,w;
}Room;
```

However, I cant add room objects to a room object. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Adding pointers to room objects instead?

Comment: In C pointers are not implied.  You have to explicitly declare them as pointers.

Comment: In addition to using pointers, you're also going to need to use a named struct so that you can include the pointers inside the struct.